# DataWeave: csv to ascii table

Tags: dataweave

With the following csv input:

```
Name,Nick
Sébastien,peudo1
Alex,peudo2
Max,Mule
```

I want the following output (plain text format):

```
| Sébastien  | peudo1  |
| Alex       | peudo2  |
| Max        | Mule    |
```

The big challenge is to have the fixed size for the ouput columns and size adjust to the biggest string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jorge-gracia said the best way is to use csv and hack around in order to have previous and last `|` then what I did is calculate the max size of the fields and the use the rightPad function

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator="|"
import * from dw::core::Strings

fun biggestLength(data: Array<{_: String}>) = 
    data flatMap ((item, index) -> 
                        item pluck ((value, key, index) -> sizeOf(value))
                 )
          maxBy ((item) -> item)       

var padding = biggestLength(payload)          
---
payload map ((item) -> 
    {
        "": "",
        (
            item mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
                {
                    (rightPad(key, padding)): rightPad(value, padding)
                }
            )
        ),
        "": ""
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following code.
Maybe it can be improved:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain

var array = (payload map [ $.Name, $.Nick ])
var nameSize = max( payload map sizeOf($.Name))
var nickSize = max( payload map sizeOf($.Nick))

---    

payload map (
    "| "  ++ $.Name ++ ((0 to (nameSize-sizeOf($.Name))) map " " joinBy  "") ++ 
    " | " ++ $.Nick ++ ((0 to (nickSize-sizeOf($.Nick))) map " " joinBy  "") ++  
    " |"
    )
    joinBy  '\n'
```

Comment: If the file is too big and you have trouble handling the huge String at the output, you can try using a similar strategy with the CSV output using an empty field at the beginning (to get the first pipe) and pipe as separator.